# SQL joining data from other tables

Tags: sql

I have the following tables:

Item (Table)
no
name
price
description

Item-custom (Table)
userid
itemid
description1
description2

If an item have a description in Item-custom table i want to show that description else i'm showing the description from item table.

I made a query where i inner join the item-custom table on item.no = item-custom.itemid. This works okay if the item have an description in the item-custom table. But if it doesn't have a description the query doesn't return any data.

How should i write this query so i always get a item record no matter if it have a description in item-custom table.

Here is what i have:

```
SELECT item.description, item-custom.description1, item-custom.description 
FROM item
INNER JOIN item-custom ON item.no = item-custom.itemid
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using a left join instead of an inner join. You can read more about left joins [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) 
An inner join only takes the records from both tables that has non nullable columns. So if description is empty (NULL) the record won't be shown. While using a left join it will.

```
SELECT item.description, item-custom.description1, item-custom.description 
FROM item
LEFT JOIN item-custom ON item.no = item-custom.itemid
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT item.description, item-custom.description1, item-custom.description 
FROM item
LEFT OUTER JOIN item-custom ON item.no = item-custom.itemid
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it fits more to your condition

Sql Server:

```
SELECT ISNULL(item.description, item-custom.description) as descriptin
FROM item
LEFT OUTER JOIN item-custom ON item.no = item-custom.itemid
```

MySql

```
SELECT COALESCE(item.description, item-custom.description) as descriptin
FROM item
LEFT OUTER JOIN item-custom ON item.no = item-custom.itemid
```

`ISNULL` or `COALESCE` Return the first non-NULL argument

Answer (score 0):

Try with where clause instead

```
SELECT item.description, item-custom.description1, item-custom.description 
FROM item as item , item-custom as item-custom
WHERE  item.no = item-custom.itemid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN item-custom.description2 IS NOT NULL 
THEN item-custom.description2 
ELSE item.description END, ...
```